# I'm getting "iw3mp.exe has stopped working" on Multiplayer in Windows 7

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

So recently I decided I wanted to play COD4 again, so I downloaded and installed from Steam. The single player runs fine, but the multiplayer errors out everytime: "iw3mp.exe has stopped working".

I've seen a few fixes for Vista around the net. Please do not respond with the "Stereo Mixer" fix, because there is no such thing in Windows 7.

What do I need to do to fix this error so I can play COD4 multiplayer again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar problem with Windows 7. It may be related to how Windows 7 uses Realtek sound card/mic input. [This](http://forums.firingsquad.com/t5/Software-and-Applications/COD-4-iw3mp-exe-has-stopped-working/m-p/281230) forum and [this](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-132360-cod-4-modernwarfare-pc-iw3mp-exe-has-stopped) one seems to indicate that it might solve your problem.

NOTE: I have not yet been able to try this solution yet. Have given up on PC and am sticking with PS3!!

Comment: You're correct. I ended up plugging in an old USB headset (because it has it's own sound drivers) just to boot the game, then I pull it out once it's booted. It works fine after that.